# IPN with Paypal recurring payments

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to to set up a subscription system with recurring payments and IPN notifications but I was reading that there is no way of setting the notify_url from the API.

Answer (score 1):

The CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile request doesn't by itself seem to do the actual recurring transactions,except for the "INITAMT" which you may set (any amount to be charged immediately upon profile creation, say a "set up fee" or something). If it does I think there should not be something like this [Recurring Payments With Direct Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/#id08669F0705Z) for instance.

The DoDirectPayment request allows a RECURRING parameter and this requires the "recurring payment profile be already created" (using the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile request) . DoDirectPayment also allows NOTIFYURL parameter .

So the IPN should be returning all that is applicable for recurring payments. 
See [IPN recurring payment variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB080EYK) - ones that are related to "recurring payment profile creation". You could identify this matching the "PROFILEREFERENCE" param you set with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile against "rp_invoice_id" in the IPN .

[IPN subscription variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB0901HT) - ones that are related to the first and following subscription  payments. You could identify this matching the "INVNUM" you set with DoDirectPayment against the "invoice" in the IPN .  It also returns "payment_date" and "payment_status" .

I haven't tested this though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are right. There is no way to send notify url with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile. The only way to set it is to set it in IPN settings in paypal, but of course you won't be able to make different urls for different subscriptions.

Comment: Is there any way to test in the sandbox?

Comment: Yes, it is working the same way in sandbox. You just set IPN url in paypal IPN settings and it will work.